# Can I Use Google Home To Automatically Chromecast My Own Content

Tags: chromecast, actions-on-google, google-home

I have a working "Action On Google" that we programmed.

I separately created a website that Chromecasts video (based on Google's sample code).

However, what I would REALLY like to have is speak to my Google Home, then automatically have content (ideally an image + audio, then a video right after) cast to the Chromecast.

Is this technically possible exclusively through the Google Home interaction?

Alternately, is there a way to cast image + audio at the same time through a website (and what code do I need to do so)?

Answer (score 2):

Right there is no API for third-party developers to programmatically send content to a Chromecast.